# Extract parameter value from response body using Newman

Tags: postman, newman

I am trying to extract a specific value returned from an API response, example below. I have extracted the entire body using `response.stream.toString()` using Newman.

However I am struggling to extract the value `48.00` below when using Newman to run a postman collection.

Is there a way I could use the JSON path (x.cost) to extract the value rather than having to manipulate the string returned for the entire body?

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
{
    "cost": 48.00,
    "min": 4.000,
    "max": 266.95
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't something simple like this work here:

```js
const newman = require('newman');

newman.run({
   collection: 'collection.json'
}).on('request', (error, args) => {
   console.log(JSON.parse(args.response.stream.toString()).cost);
});
```

I'm taking a guess and assuming that you're using Newman as a library here.

Comment: That works : ), thank you Danny! Appreciate it & yes I was using Newman as a library, apologies for not making that clear.

Comment: Feel free to accept this as the answer, you would need to hit a tick somewhere 